# v-model prints [object Object] instead of the JSON string

Tags: json, vuejs2

**I have a JSON object that I want users to edit.**

When I print it plainly, like `{{json}}` I get the string, `{"car":{"color":"blue"}}`. But when I print it in any sort of  editable field, like

```
<input v-model="json">
```

I get this:

[image]

***Things I've tried:***

- `html:v-model` / `html:value` - Empty input
- `<textarea v-model="json">{{json}}</textarea>` - I get `[object Object]`, BUT when I inspect the element, I see the JSON printed like a string - which is what I want!

### ***How do I get v-model to print JSON as a string in an input?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `JSON.stringify(someObject)` to get the stringified version of an object, however you cannot bind this via `v-model`.

If I understand you correctly, you do actually want the user to edit the stringified json and not provide input fields for the object properties? (The latter would be a much cleaner solution and could easily be achieved with a `v-for="(value, key) in object"` though)

But if that's the case, you also have to consider what to do when the user enters invalid json.

My approach to this would be to use a stringified version of the object to bind to the textarea `v-model` and `watch` it to determine on any change if it is a valid and parsable json format.

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ol9nn9j566
It'd probably need some debouncing, and better error handling but it should get you started.